# J-invariants, Elliptic Curves, Cross Ratio

Tags: algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves, algebraic-curves, cross-ratio

Let $E$ be an elliptic curve in $\mathbb P^2$ and $p$ be any point on $E$. From $p$ we can draw four tangent lines to $E$ and let $\lambda$ be the cross ratio of their slopes. How can we prove that $\lambda$ is independent of $p$?

I saw this in a note on elliptic curves which suggests that from above we can see the j-invariant is really a invariant.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is it clear in what order you take these slopes?

Comment: @Lubin You mean the order to take cross ratio? I think it does not matter. For my understanding it means we can choose an order to make the cross ratios the same for different $p$. (or equivalently, there are $24$ orders to take cross ratios, and the sum of square of them is independent of $p$ )